# Filter Unit from List

Tags: scala

Given a `List`, I'd like to filter out any elements that equal `Unit - ()`.

Is there a better way to filter than through this code?

```
scala> List( () ).filter( x => x != () )
<console>:8: warning: comparing values of types Unit and Unit using `!=' will 
always yield false
                  List( () ).filter( x => x != () )
                                            ^
    res10: List[Unit] = List()
```

Comment: I like both answers. How do I decide?

Comment: The reason it says that it will always yield false is because `Unit` is a singleton type. What's the actual use case where you'd need to filter `Unit` values from a list? Are you using `List[Any]` for some reason?

Comment: @DaoWen, using a for expression, I'm iterating over a `List[JsObject]`. For each element, I'd like to create a tuple (String , String) representing a key-value. However, if the key is "invalid," then I return `None` during the for expression. But, regarding my issue in particular (aside from question), I used a `list.flatMap( x => x match { case Some(x) => List(x); case _ => None })` and then all `None`'s will be ignored (maybe that's the wrong term?) in my output list

Comment: See [my answer to your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19303286/1427124).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd go with this:

```
List(1, (), 4, (), 9, (), 16) filter (_ != ())
res0: List[AnyVal] = List(1, 4, 9, 16)
```

Comment: Although the other answers look good to me, this one looks *arguably* most concise.

Answer (score 3):

You could use pattern matching:

```
list.filter(_ match {
   case x : Unit => false
   case x => true})
```

Answer (score 3):

```
scala> List(()).filterNot(_.isInstanceOf[Unit])
res0: List[Unit] = List()

scala> List((),1,2).filterNot(_.isInstanceOf[Unit])
res1: List[AnyVal] = List(1, 2)
```