# Cannot prove that Unit <:< (T, U)

Tags: scala

When trying to remove all `Unit - ()` from a list, I tried to call `toMap`.

```
scala> List((), ()).filter(_ != ()).toMap
<console>:8: error: Cannot prove that Unit <:< (T, U).
              List((), ()).filter(_ != ()).toMap
                                           ^
```

What does this error mean?

For a `List`, I'd like to create a map of all tuples `(String, String)` for non-Unit elements, but some of the values can be null.

```
scala> val x = List((), (), (3,4)).filter(_ != ()).toMap
<console>:7: error: Cannot prove that Any <:< (T, U).
       val x = List((), (), (3,4)).filter(_ != ()).toMap
                                                   ^

scala> val x = List((), (), (3,4)).filter(_ != ())
x: List[Any] = List((3,4))

scala> x.toMap
<console>:9: error: Cannot prove that Any <:< (T, U).
              x.toMap
                ^
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah! Now [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19301559/filter-unit-from-list) makes a little more sense. Still not sure what you're doing to produce this mixed `Unit`/`Tuple2` list though.

This should work:

```
List((), (), (3,4)).collect { case t@(_: Int, _: Int) => t }.toMap
```

Note that I'm using [variable binding](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/case-classes-and-pattern-matching.html#sec:var-binding) here (binding the match to `t`) to return the same Tuple2 instance we matched rather than creating a new one.

By using `collect` you convert the type of your list from `List[Any]` to `List[(Int, Int)]`, which is what `toMap` wants since it's expecting some `List[(A,B)]`.

---

***Note: Although this answer should work for you, I still think your design is flawed. You'd be better off fixing the underlying design flaw rather than treating the symptoms like this.***

It looks like this would be a good fit for using [Scala's `Option` type](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option). In this case, your sample list would become `List(None, None, Some((3,4)))`, or you could write it as `List(None, None, Some(3->4))` for readability (nested parenthesis like that can get confusing).

If you use `Option` then the type of your list becomes `List[Option[(Int, Int)]]`, which should be much nicer to deal with than a `List[Any]`. To get rid of the `None` entries and get the desired `List[(Int,Int)]` you can just call `flatten`:

```
List(None, None, Some(3->4)).flatten
// res0: List[(Int, Int)] = List((3,4))
List(None, None, Some(3->4)).flatten.toMap
// res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(3 -> 4)
```

However, it would be ***even better*** if you can avoid putting the `None` entries in your list in the first place. If you're producing this list using a Scala for comprehension, you could [use a guard in your for expression](http://daily-scala.blogspot.com/2010/01/guard-sugar.html) to remove the invalid elements from the output.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my flawed design. I'm using `None`'s b/c, when using a for expression to iterate over a `List[JsObject]`, I need to return a field (I believe) as part of the for-expression's `yield(...`). My code looks like: `for { jsObj <- jsonObjs; val x = ...` where the return type is `List[Option(String, JsValue)]`. Is it possible to "skip" values in a for expression? For values that I need to skip, I'm returning `None`.

Comment: @Kevin - Yes, you can skip values. That's what my comment about using a guard in the for comprehension was about. Read the examples on the blog I linked to and it should be clear how to do it. By the way, I had similar problems the first time I was writing a for comprehension in Scala. After I learned how to leverage guards and the `Nothing` type I was able to do a lot to clean up my code!

Answer (score 2):

It means that the type of an element in the list can't be viewed as a tuple which is required to build a Map. A Map in a sense is a collection of tuples (and more).

Illustration:

```
scala> List(1).toMap
<console>:8: error: Cannot prove that Int <:< (T, U).
          List(1).toMap
                  ^
scala> List(1 -> 2).toMap
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 2)
```

I can build a map from a list of tuples, but not from a list of single cardinality elements.

Maybe you mean to say `.map` instead of `.toMap`? ;)

Answer (score 1):

All in one go:

```
scala> val l2 = List(1 -> 3, (), 4 -> 4, (), 9 -> 4, (), 16 -> 7)
l2: List[Any] = List((1,3), (), (4,4), (), (9,4), (), (16,7))

scala> (l2 collect { case (a, b) => (a, b) }).toMap
res4: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Any,Any] = Map(1 -> 3, 4 -> 4, 9 -> 4, 16 -> 7)
```

Better typed:

```
scala> (l2 collect { case (i: Int, j: Int) => (i, j) }).toMap
res5: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 3, 4 -> 4, 9 -> 4, 16 -> 7)
```

Comment: so the `better typed` answer would only be necessary if I wanted to only create a `Map[Int, Int]`, right?

Comment: You should want to avoid `Any` as much as possible!