# In Scala,Set convert to Map error.Cannot prove that (String, Class[?0]) forSome { type ?0 } <:< (T, U)

Tags: scala, type-conversion

This code is working properly

```
def init = {
    var jobPackageClassSet:Set[Class[_]] = ClassUtil.getClassSetFromPackge("com.test.job");
    val jobAnnotion = classOf[JobAnnotation];
    val a = jobPackageClassSet.asScala.filter { cls =>
      cls.isAnnotationPresent(jobAnnotion)
    }.map(cls => cls.getAnnotation(jobAnnotion).jobName -> cls.getName).toMap
  }
```

But when I change the code `(cls.getAnnotation(jobAnnotion).jobName -> cls)` as below,it causes error

```
 def init = {
    var jobPackageClassSet = ClassUtil.getClassSetFromPackge("com.test.job");
    val jobAnnotion = classOf[JobAnnotation];
    val a = jobPackageClassSet.asScala.filter { cls =>
      cls.isAnnotationPresent(jobAnnotion)
    }.map(cls => cls.getAnnotation(jobAnnotion).jobName -> cls).toMap
  }
```

> Error:
>
> Cannot prove that (String, Class[?0]) forSome { type ?0 }  (T, U). not
>   enough arguments for method toMap

From this question:[Cannot prove that Unit <:< (T, U)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19303054/cannot-prove-that-unit-t-u,I) change my code to this, is still the error.

```
def init = {
    var jobPackageClassSet = ClassUtil.getClassSetFromPackge("com.test.job");
    val jobAnnotion = classOf[JobAnnotation];
    val a = jobPackageClassSet.asScala.filter { cls =>
      cls.isAnnotationPresent(jobAnnotion)
    }.map(cls => cls.getAnnotation(jobAnnotion).jobName -> cls).collect{case t@(k:String,v:Class[_]=>t)}.toMap
  }
```

Has anyone got this earlier?

Comment: Please highlight the error text so that people will get to know about that quickly and easily.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `toMap` can only be called on a sequence (or set) of pairs, but for some reason you have a sequence of existential types, each of which is a pair. You want `(String, Class[?0] forSome { type ?0 })` rather than `(String, Class[?0]) forSome { type ?0 }`, though it isn't obvious to me why your current code gets the wrong type (what is the return type of `ClassUtil.getClassSetFromPackge`)?

I expect `.map(cls => cls.getAnnotation(jobAnnotion).jobName -> (cls: Class[_]))` or `.map { case cls: Class[_] => cls.getAnnotation(jobAnnotion).jobName -> cls }` should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old issue, but I post for whoever arrives here nowadays :)

I had same error today with other types:

```
val seq: Seq[(String, com.company.complicatedUnionClass)] = //.....
val mapped = seq.toMap

Cannot prove that (String, _ >: com.company.complicatedUnionClass) forSome { type _$8 >: com.company.complicatedUnionClass }  <:< (T, U)
```

adding explicitly the [T,U] parameter in toMap solved the compilation error

```
val seq: Seq[(String, com.company.complicatedUnionClass)] = //.....
val mapped = seq.toMap[String, com.company.complicatedUnionClass]
```